# What are some examples of tasks in which, currently, neuroevolution outperforms gradient-based approaches?

Tags: neural-networks, neat, neuroevolution

Note: I am NOT asking for general advantages of neuroevolution over standard approaches (e.g.: architecture search, parallelization), I am asking for examples of tasks in which, currently, neuroevolved networks outperform ANNs trained with gradient-based techniques. Of course, this is not opinion based, as I am asking for examples based on facts.